# Query to find and replace a specific word in SQL Database without affecting the data along with it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a DB with a table which holds entries about the information of the industries the people belong to with a primary industry and a secondary industry :

for ex : Aerospace and Defense,Retail, Wholesale and Distribution
         Research and Development,Technology, Media and Telecommunications
etc.

there are around 500 such entries. I want the separating symbol ',' only between the primary industry and the secondary industry and nowhere in the industry name.

for ex. : 
                 Aerospace and Defense,Retail, Wholesale and Distribution

should look like

Aerospace and Defense,Retail Wholesale and Distribution (without a comma)

is there anyway this can be achieved , ie replacing the comma from the  secondary term without affecting the primary term.

Comment: How does your DB table look? What columns are there? How are the entries stored?

Comment: Do you really only want to change the secondary term, or are there cases where the extraneous comma is in the primary term too (eg "Retail, Wholesale and Distribution,Aerospace and Defence"). Also is the data in a TEXT column or a VARCHAR column?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have the wrong table design.  A single column should never list a bunch of values separated by commas.  This is a nightmare to deal with (as you are discovering).

Instead, there should be a separate table linking people to industries, allowing multiple rows per person:

```
person_id          industry
1                  Retail, Wholesale and Distribution
1                  Aerospace and Defense
2                  Retail, Wholesale and Distribution
```

Then join to this table whenever you need to find the industries for a person or group of people.

Obviously, this makes your comma problem go away.

Of course, sometimes you are stuck with a dumb table design.  If so, you could come up with a replacement solution using `replace()` (thanks to other answers for mentioning the replace function).

**Update:**

[Here is a working SQLFiddle solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4122a/1):

Updated to use `replace()`:

```
update bad_design 
   set bad_design.industries = 
       replace(bad_design.industries, from_str, to_str)
    from (
      select * from bad_design join replacements 
         on replace(bad_design.industries, from_str, to_str) <> '' 
    ) as a
    where a.person_id = bad_design.person_id;
```

Note: this won't perform multiple replacements on the same string in one pass.  You would need something more to do that, such as a recursive query.

Comment: As the requirement is likely needed to aid searches, you could perhaps generate the linking table and query against that even if you're unable to change the original table structure.  I generally try to avoid triggers but would be a reasonable way to maintain it...

Comment: @chrisb, thanks for the suggestion.  Ideally the place that updates this field could simply update both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a replace on the table...

```
select replace(column_name,'Retail, Wholesale','Retail Wholesale')
from table
```

or update

```
update table
set column_name = replace(column_name,'Retail, Wholesale','Retail Wholesale')
```

This basically replaces the string 'Retail, Wholesale' with 'Retail Wholesale' in a given column.

Comment: And yes, you should really have another 2 tables.  One for the types of industry and another table that ties the types to the table you are working with.

Comment: If you were stuck with the table schema and did want to use replace, you could probably get away with replace(column_name, ', ', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SUBSTRING(), INSTRING() functions to find first comma in your string  and REPLACE() second comma judging by your example. Questions to ask you: Is it safe to assume that you always need to replace second comma in your string? Are all your strings uniform or similar to your example? Etc... 
This example assumes all that above. Also, replace dual table with any other table and Oracle syntax with your version of SQL - SUBSTR()=SUBSTRING in SQL Server as far as I know. The same applies to INSTR()...:

```
SELECT str -- orig str --
     , SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ',', 1, 1)) first_string
     , REPLACE(SUBSTR(str,  INSTR(str, ',', 1, 1)+1), ',', '') second_string
  FROM
   (
    SELECT 'Aerospace and Defense,Retail, Wholesale and Distribution' str 
      FROM dual
    )
  /
```

Output (tested) - you will need to concatenate first_string and second_string using SQL server sytax. In Oracle it would be SELECT first_string ||''|| second_string FROM...:

```
  Aerospace and Defense, Retail Wholesale and Distribution
```

Create DUAL table in SQL SERVER: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/20/sql-server-select-from-dual-dual-equivalent/